# ngFor Elements in Row

Tags: css

Hello currently I'm trying to display my items from ngFor in a row, but it's not working.

My Code:

```
<ng-container>
    <div class="model" *ngFor="let model of modelService;" >
        <div id="Ppicture"  > {{model.modelPic}} </div>
        <div id="Name" > {{model.modelName}} </div>
        <div id="Age"> {{model.modelAge}} </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

CSS:

```
ng-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.model{
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I also tried to put display flex into the .model class, but flex is only putting the text in a row, not the boxes.

That's how it looks like
https://ibb.co/VLSKVcS

Answer (score 0):

try to put `width: 100%` in `ng-container`.

```
ng-container{
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ng-container>
  <div class="model_sec">
   <div class="model" *ngFor="let model of modelService;" >
     <div id="Ppicture"  > {{model.modelPic}} </div>
     <div id="Name" > {{model.modelName}} </div>
     <div id="Age"> {{model.modelAge}} </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</ng-container>
  


ng-container {
        display: block;
        width: 100%; 
      }
.model {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border: solid 1px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}
.model_sec {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%    
}
```

Comment: No changes. Same like before

Comment: please show me a screenshot with inspect element and CSS of model_sec

Comment: I finally got it with a whole replace with your code! Ty very much